# In which way should I design the layout of a website?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I am a newbie in web design. Now I am frequently using float property to design my layouts. I also have learned a bit both about grid system and flexbox system. My question is which method should i use and why, is there any other method other than floats, grids and flexbox to design the layout of a website? If so please explain.

Comment: You should take a loop at bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Before doing anything just check there stats on https://caniuse.com/ So you can clearly understand in which you have to make your design

Comment: Your question comes entirely down to personal opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, no single method is overarching. If there was one, we'd all be using it and nothing else.

However, it sounds like you might be asking if flex is better than grid, grid better than flex, floats better than grid, etc. I use a combination of all of these in most projects I work on. They each have strengths and weaknesses that need to be utilized or avoided in certain situations.

You will, however, need to be aware of browser support (or lack thereof) and will need to provide fallbacks for those cases (e.g., [CSS grids and IE11](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid)).

Answer (score 0):

The best method to design your site layout is to start with a piece of scratch paper and a pencil. Draw rough drafts of where you envision the different parts of the site, what page leads to another page, etc. Then figure out how to make it all functional.

There is no *one method* of coding, you develop your style through experience using a combination of any of several coding languages. Decide first what you want to see on your page, then look for a solution. It is a process.

Comment: Please read the description in full. I am looking for a standard method of coding, not the concept.

Comment: (Answer edited) Please understand that there is no one coding language that will do it all. You are just starting to learn, take several of the online tutorials, watch the youtube videos, Never stop learning.